# Mac wont boot and fan runs high

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

My Mid 2013 macbook pro recently will no longer boot. I was using it normally (no excessive use) and then all of a sudden it just went black and shut off immediately. I can no longer boot it (I got it to boot once but now it't having the same problem).

Basically, when I press the power button to turn it on, the fan runs really high then stops and wont boot. I have no idea what the problem is. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Apple's official guide has several good steps. http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1367

I would start with resetting the SMC: the System Management Controller.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

If that doesn't work, reset the NVRAM (which isn't on the list) followed by attempting to boot to internet recovery.

- [NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) - Command Option P R
- [Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) - Command R

Past that, you would need to open the machine and start removing all components that aren't part of the "minimal system" or take it to a technician that does that professionally.

Comment: Tried that, sometimes it gets to the bong noise but then nothing again.

Comment: I have tried all 3 methods as well as opening it up and cleaning out the fan a little bit. I would remove the fan but don't have the tools for it. I might take it to the apple store or mac experts but I'm afraid I might be SOL.

Comment: got it to boot, any suggestions while its working? Think its probably going to cut out again soon

Comment: @Raymond Backup your data.

Comment: Way ahead of you. Already done.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed MacBook Pro stuck in Sleep and Fans running high. All you need to do is open up case and unplug the fans from motherboard! Somehow the temperature sensing must be in fan air and it senses high temp and shuts down computer with fans on high. Some how restarting computer doesn't reset things (design fault or firmware bug).
But UNPLUG FANS and you're good to go. I did this while powered on and it sprang into life! Later I checked it powers down and reboots. 
Don't forget to plug fans in again before completion and fans "hey presto" run at normal speed. 
Apple engineers couldnt fix this and said we had to buy new board or computer $2k+. 
Good luck

Comment: This seems dangerous to disable cooling long enough to boot to the OS. Better to just power on long enough for POST  and then power it immediately off. Reconnecting the cables at that point so calling is in place seems prudent

Comment: Its not sensitive to having the fans off as its all open at this point and everything's exposed for cooling. Still as you say re-connect the fans asap why not

Comment: I'll plus one the answer after thinking through the scenario - MBP with heat pipes connected but blower off probably won't go too hot before the thermal protection kicks in. Also, flat rate repair means $300 should fix the damage if needed.

Comment: Please folks don’t worry about cooling doing this simple fix. The MBP base lid is off so its electronics is not in an enclosure. The 2 impeller fans running are designed to expel air from the MBP enclosure but lid-off are now not doing anything as they are taking air from your room and blowing it back to the room! I ran my MBP testing for 5 mins fans off mode and did touch test the electronic parts and none were excessively hot. So relax and test your MBP briefly before re-plugging in the 2 fans and screwing on the base lid. Then have a drink to celebrate the fix and money saved. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem as well. Right now I am running my mac book with no battery and the charger in. This normally makes it work. I am starting to think that the battery is sliding around because the brackets attached to my battery broke off (screws that hold the battery down). I temperaily had a piece of metal wedged to keep it from sliding and this did the trick for about a week. Then it started again. I am not sure what is going on but it all started for both me and my roommate after using the HDMI adapter accessory...